# Remove subfolders from URL

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, htaccess

I am having a tough time removing the subfolders from the URL in my WordPress site.

Currently, the URL format is:
`www.mysite.com/subfolder/index.php/category/postname`

I would like to remove both the subfolder AND index.php from the URL.

The site must stay in a subfolder of root on my server.

My current `htaccess` file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried to add the following, although it did not work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the WP site url and home url differ in Settings / General. The home url should be `example.com`, while the site url (where WP lives) should be `example.com/wp` (or wherever you put it).

You can hardcode these in your config file:

```
define('WP_HOME',    'http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wp');
```

WP should know how to take things from there, and place the .htaccess where it should be.

In case it doesn't, my own site's folder looks like this:

- .htaccess
- index.php
- wp

The index.php file contains:

```
<?php
// WordPress view bootstrapper
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );
require( './wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

And the .htaccess contains:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Regarding the `/index.php` bit in URLs generated by WP, it means WP is (incorrectly?) finding that your site cannot manage permalinks. (Can I wager that this is because you're using [Nginx](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx)?)

Assuming you know better than WP, add a must-use plugin in your wp-content/mu-plugins folder, e.g. a force-permalinks.php file:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'got_rewrite', '__return_true' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want. Can you please elaborate your question a bit more?

If you want URLs like `www.mysite.com/subfolder/postname` (where the `subfolder` is where your WordPress install is), then just go to **Settings > Permalinks** and change it to **Post Name**.

**EDIT**

If your WordPress install is in `subfolder` and you want URLs like `www.mysite.com/category/postname`, then set both the **WordPress Address** and **Site Address** to `www.mysite.com` and in **Permalinks**, choose *Custom Structure* and use this tag `/%category%/%postname%`.