# Show posts in a parent directory

Tags: posts, directory

I have a Wordpress in a directory like mydomain.com/page/ and I'd like to show the posts on my parent directory, like mydomain.com/my-post-url
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I still need the pages to be under mydomain.com/page/about, mydomain.com/page/cart
I need only the posts to be shown on a parent directory of the WP website

EDIT 2: I have a plain intro HTML file on the root folder, that's why changing the configuration doens't work.
I need to keep this mydomain.com/index.html custom html

Comment: Please refer **https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112745/remove-subfolders-from-url**

Answer (score 0):

Try this below Permalink Settings changes.
[image]